# What is this pink flowered volunteer plant that appeared this spring?

Tags: identification, flowers

This plant showed up in our garden this spring. It just began blooming a couple days ago.

[image]

Here are buds, getting ready.

[image]

Is this some kind of phlox? The plant itself is about 2 1/2 feet tall and looks quite civilized.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You guessed right! This is [*Phlox paniculata*, or tall phlox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phlox_paniculata).

#### Characteristics:

- Opposite leaves
- Slightly pubescent stems/leaves
- Lance-shaped (lanceolata) leaves
- Inflorescence: cyme
- 5 petals
- Rotate/stellate petal placement
- Herbaceous perennial
- Height (2-3 1/2 feet)
- Habit
- Everything else :)

These grow wild in my woods, but there are many cultivars developed for garden use. That is a very nice volunteer plant, and I know a good many people who would be envious of such a healthy volunteer specimen in their garden.

[image]

Comment: I like that term volunteer. This particular bed is much happier this year after I cut back a lot of rampaging English ivy.